Compiler error when defining an interface
I have the following type and interface definition:
type RegionData = [string, string, string, string, string, string, string]

interface DataItem {
  [key: string]: RegionData
  modelId: string
}

I get an error:
Property 'modelId' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'RegionData'.

The above interface definition looks ok to me. But TypeScript complains. What am I missing?

The docs explain why you see this error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures.
While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type. This is because a string index declares that obj.property is also available as obj["property"]. In the following example, name’s type does not match the string index’s type, and the type checker gives an error
